# Blank screen but View Tree is populated in layout inspector

Tags: android, layout-inspector

The screen on app is blank (by blank I mean its all white and nothing is appearing), and when I view it via Layout Inspector in android studio the 'View Tree` is populated from elements in XML layout file. But the screen is blank both in app and in layout inspector. In logs I can't see any apparent reason for this happening.
This doesn't happen always, its a random thing. The 'View tree' remains same even when the screen is not blank. 
Any ideas why is this happening ?

**UPDATE**
There is difference between randered layout and blank layout in Layout Inspector. Under 'Properties Table'->drawing The blank screen view has following values : 
[image: Blank screen drawing properties for any view in layout]

and rendered layout has following :

[image: Rendered screen drawing properties for any view in layout]

Comment: try clean your project and then rebuild it.

Comment: This is random thing, new installation also does this after of couple of times going back and forth between same screens.

Comment: This is a strange question, but you aren't using any `SurfaceHolder`s anywhere are you?  Perhaps a `GLSurfaceView` or `NativeActivity`?  I had a similar issue once.

Comment: I agree on the strange part. No nothing like that.